# Table Sorter sort by span title?

Tags: sort, table

I'm using table sorter plugin to sort a table on my website.

One column has only unsortable signs as content.
However I'm trying to sort this column by value.

It's the column IMDb here: https://flimmerzimmer.eu/filmothek/

So I added span title to the span with corresponding value but it's not sortable.

Any ideas how to sort this column?

Comment: You'd have to ask the plugin developer (assuming it's not you) how to go about doing this.  The plugin developer's code may not allow what you're doing.  If you are the plugin developer then it would be super helpful to include your markup and scripting here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TonyDjukic I asked the developer: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/sort-by-span-title/
Last answer was 3 years ago. I don't think I'll get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just added:

```
"<p style=\"display: none;\">" . $rating . "</p>";
```